# Converting bytes memory to bytes calldata

Tags: solidity, bytes

I am getting the following error:

`Error: Type bytes memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes calldata.`

So I was wondering if it was possible to convert from bytes memory to bytes calldata, as an external function I'm using requires bytes calldata but I can only decode it into bytes memory.

Thanks in advance :D

EDIT: I have made a contract which represents my issue as the actual one is quite long.
The error occurs on line 9 with the error `TypeError: Type bytes memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes calldata.`.

I tried putting bytes calldata instead of bytes as the type in the abi decode part was I ended up with the error `ParserError: Expected ',' but got 'calldata'`.

If I replace calldata with memory when specifying the types of the variables (`uint a, bytes memory b, bytes memory c`), I get `TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from bytes memory to bytes calldata requested.` on line 11.

At this point, I don't know what to do and I've looked through many websites to try to find the answer. Here's an example contract which is similar to the part of my contract that contains the errors.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Foo {    
    // I can't change the parameters of this function but I can change the content
    function bar (bytes calldata data) public {
        (uint a, bytes calldata b, bytes calldata c) = abi.decode(data, (uint, bytes, bytes));
        
        qux(c);
    }
    
    // I can't change this function at all
    function qux (bytes calldata data) public {
        // Do something here
    }
    
    // I can change this function, the parameters are just an example
    function baz (uint _a, bytes calldata _b, bytes calldata _c) public {
        uint a = _a;
        bytes calldata b = _b;
        bytes calldata c = _c;
        
        bytes memory data = abi.encode(
            a,
            b,
            c
        );

        bar(data);
    }
}
```

Baz is the function that I call externally (aka the starting point).

Comment: You should write the program that give this error.

Comment: @AlirezaZojaji Done :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer was given to me on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/okhd48/converting_bytes_memory_to_bytes_calldata/) so here is the fixed contract for anyone who may need it :D :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract Foo {
    // I can't change the parameters of this function but I can change the content
    function bar (bytes calldata data) public {
        (uint a, bytes memory b, bytes memory c) = abi.decode(data, (uint, bytes, bytes));
        this.qux(c);
    }
    
    // I can't change this function at all
    function qux (bytes calldata data) public {
        // Do something here
    }
    
    // I can change this function, the parameters are just an example
    function baz (uint _a, bytes calldata _b, bytes calldata _c) public {
        uint a = _a;
        bytes calldata b = _b;
        bytes calldata c = _c;
        
        bytes memory data = abi.encode(
            a,
            b,
            c
        );
    
        this.bar(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: You saved my time!

Comment: For those who didn't get it right away, calling the function on the 'this' object allows us to pass `memory` params to a function that accepts `calldata` params, essentially "converting" `memory` --> `storage`.

Answer (score 2):

Change all `calldata` statements to `memory`.

Solidity language ordinary uses `calldata` statement in interfaces for the functions input parameters instead of `memory`.

Comment: But I said that I can't change the parameters of 2 of the functions which require calldata...

Comment: You must change  ALL `calldata`s to `memory`. In this case no error is occured.

Comment: But I can't change ALL of the calldatas to memory. I can't change one function at all that requires calldata and I can't change the parameters of another that requires calldata so how am I going to change ALL calldatas to memory?