# How to decode abi.encodeWithSignature and get the encoded values?

Tags: solidity, abi, foundry

I'm running Foundry and trying to decode the encoded signature, but I'm getting "EvmError: Revert" error when running the below code. It appears to be something I'm doing incorrectly with the abi.decode

```
uint256 internal constant TOKENS_IN_POOL = 1_000_000e18;
address payable internal attacker;
bytes memory approvePaylaod = abi.encodeWithSignature("approve(address,uint256)",address(attacker),TOKENS_IN_POOL);

address payable addressAttacker;
uint256 num;
(addressAttacker,num) = abi.decode(approvePaylaod, (address,uint256));
```

Is this the correct way to decode an encoded function signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's review the payload generated by calling `abi.encodeWithSignature`. It should contain the following:

`[4-byte function selector] [32-byte zero-padded address] [32-byte uint256]`

What's special about it is the 4-byte function selector at the beginning. In order to properly decode the payload, you will need to remove the first 4 bytes from it. You will need to use a library in order to be able to perform this on memory-based bytes (`bytes memory`). But for the sake of demonstration, I will show you how to do this on a calldata-based payload:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.x;

contract TestArray { 
    uint256 internal constant TOKENS_IN_POOL = 1_000_000e18;
    address internal attacker = 0xBAd0000000000000000000000000000000000Bad;

   function encode() public view returns(bytes memory) {
        bytes memory approvePaylaod = abi.encodeWithSignature("approve(address,uint256)",address(attacker),TOKENS_IN_POOL);
        return approvePaylaod;
   }

   function decode(bytes calldata approvePaylaod) public pure returns(address,uint256) {
        address addressAttacker;
        uint256 num;
        // `approvePaylaod[4:]` basically ignores the first 4 bytes of the payload
        (addressAttacker,num) = abi.decode(approvePaylaod[4:], (address,uint256));
        return (addressAttacker,num);
   }
}
```

Note that I'm using Solidity v0.8.x, since slicing calldata bytes is a feature that is not available for old versions of Solidity.

Comment: Thank you! Any ideas on how I can do this with bytes memory? without using calldata

Comment: You could possibly pass memory params to a function that defines call data inputs, as demonstrated by the following SE answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/103543/51644